# When I try to retrieve data from firebase using stream builder ('List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String')

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

When I want to get data from Firebase using Streambuilder and I want the image and some text from firebase firestone

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return   StreamBuilder (
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("products").snapshots(),
  builder: (_, snapshot){
  if(!snapshot.hasData){
  return Center(
  child:Text("Loading"),);
  }else{
    return GridView.builder(
      itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
      gridDelegate:
      new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext contex, int index) {
        DocumentSnapshot data = snapshot.data.docs[index];
        return  
        Single_prod (
          product_name: data['name'],
          prod_pictures: data['imageurl'],
          prod_oldprice: data['old_price'],
          prod_price: data["price"],
        );
      },
    );
  }
  }
  );
```

When it Calling Single_prod class it happened in this class image and text are shown
Single_prod class:

```
class Single_prod extends  StatefulWidget {
  final product_name;
  final prod_pictures;
  //final prod_oldprice;
  final prod_price;

  const Single_prod(
      {Key key,
      this.product_name,
      this.prod_pictures,
      this.prod_oldprice,
      this.prod_price});

  @override
  _Single_prodState createState() => _Single_prodState();
}
```

I get this error:

> Type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'String'
> The relevant error-causing widget was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `product_name: data.data()['name']` , same thing for the rest of your product items. Somewhere also in your returned data, you are getting a List, and trying to assign it to a string. Which element in your document snapshot in firestore is a List object?

For pictures, try this `prod_pictures: data.data()['imageurl'][0]`.

Comment: sorry to disturb you sir but the image can't set here same, error here. The text elements are shown correctly

Comment: There's no disturbance, don't worry about it, but I just don't understand, is it working, or not?

Comment: Yes sir it's working for text type data but when I try to retrive images same error occur

Comment: for pictures, try this ` prod_pictures: data.data()['imageurl'][0]`, if it works, we can work through it.

Comment: You're most welcome! Please accept and mark this an answer to your post if you don't mind, I'd appreciate it.